# Marshalling the same object in two different ways using standard JAXB?

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

I have a Person class (annotated with `@XmlRootElement`) in Java with two properties (name, birthday), which I need to marshal in two different ways, generating two different XML files.

In the first file, the Person object should contain only the name property:

```
<Person>
    <name>John Doe</name>
</Person>
```

In the second file, the Person object should contain all properties.

```
<Person>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <birthday>1980-01-01</birthday>
</Person>
```

Is there a way to achieve this with JAXB?

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You can use JAXB annotations to provide one representation, and leverage MOXy's external binding document to provide alternate representations.

**Use Case 1 - Minor Differences Between Representations**

By default MOXy's external mapping document is used to override metadata provided by annotations.  This allows you to tweak the representation between versions.  Below is a link to an answer I gave with a detailed example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432435/383861

**Use Case 2 - Major Differences Between Representations**

MOXy's external mapping document can also be used to override all the annotations.  This is useful when the representations are not related.  Below is a link to an example where I map the same object model to both the Google and Yahoo weather services:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/jaxb.properties
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html