# JAXB(MOXy) -mapping one model object to different schemas

Tags: jaxb2, moxy, oxm

I'm facing problem with mapping one model Object (for example: GroupHeader) for different schemas. Each of this schema has different namespace, But some of the complextypes has almost same structure  in each of them. So I want map this element to one java Object.
Is it possible to achieve this using JAXB?

First schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
    ....
       <xs:complexType name="GroupHeader33">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MsgId" type="Max35Text"/>
            <xs:element name="CreDtTm" type="ISODateTime"/>
           <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="BtchBookg" type="BatchBookingIndicator"/>
            <xs:element name="NbOfTxs" type="Max15NumericText"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CtrlSum" type="DecimalNumber"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt" type="ActiveCurrencyAndAmount"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IntrBkSttlmDt" type="ISODate"/>
            <xs:element name="SttlmInf" type="SettlementInformation13"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PmtTpInf" type="PaymentTypeInformation21"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="InstgAgt" type="BranchAndFinancialInstitutionIdentification4"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="InstdAgt" type="BranchAndFinancialInstitutionIdentification4"/>
        
    
    ...
```

Second schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.004.001.02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.004.001.02">
   ...
      <xs:complexType name="GroupHeader38">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MsgId" type="Max35Text"/>
            <xs:element name="CreDtTm" type="ISODateTime"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="0" name="Authstn" type="Authorisation1Choice"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="BtchBookg" type="BatchBookingIndicator"/>
            <xs:element name="NbOfTxs" type="Max15NumericText"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CtrlSum" type="DecimalNumber"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GrpRtr" type="TrueFalseIndicator"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TtlRtrdIntrBkSttlmAmt" type="ActiveCurrencyAndAmount"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IntrBkSttlmDt" type="ISODate"/>
            <xs:element name="SttlmInf" type="SettlementInformation13"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="InstgAgt" type="BranchAndFinancialInstitutionIdentification4"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="InstdAgt" type="BranchAndFinancialInstitutionIdentification4"/>
```

Sorry  for my English:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MOXy's external mapping document to apply multiple mappings do your domain model:

The following example demonstrates how to handle. If differences:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

And this example demonstrates how to handle small differences:

- [Using JAXB to support schemas with minor variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419732/using-jaxb-to-support-schemas-with-minor-variations/9432435#9432435)