# Modify XML schema without losing persisted config

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jaxb, eclipselink

I have the following schema

```xml
  <xs:complexType name="CustomPod">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="customPodGeneral" type="CustomPodGeneral"/>
      <xs:element name="properties" type="Properties"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CustomPodGeneral">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="enabled" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Properties">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="property" type="Property" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Property">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

It was like this due to the JAXB limitation on generating setters for lists (a problem I no longer have).

I want to change the schema to

```xml
  <xs:complexType name="CustomPod">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="enabled" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="properties" type="Property" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Property">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

However, there is persisted configuration which must not be lost. How can I safely modify the schema and still unmarshal existing config? It seems this is not possible using standard JAXB 3/4, but maybe its possible with Hibernate or EclipseLink Moxy?
https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/4.0/moxy/moxy.html

In other words I want what is being denied:

> Since EclipseLink MOXy 2.3, multiple mappings can be created for a
> single property using OXM metadata, with the caveat that at most one
> mapping will be readable (the rest will be "write-only").

I need to read multiple mappings and write one mapping.

**UPDATE**

Essentially I'm trying to avoid code like

```
.getCustomPod().getCustomPodGeneral().getType()
```

If I can introduce another write format, then at some point in time I could change over to reading with

```
.getCustomPod().getType()
```

Comment: Seems like you have two different versions of the schema, and while you should be able to read into CustomPod instances from both, need to pick one to write out as, and a solution for data versioning and migration. Otherwise, this answer is likely what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485341/496099